# Selenium WebDriver and ZK framework application

Tags: selenium-webdriver, zk

On a previous project i worked on, i was able to write selenium scripts conveniently by targeting the HTML attributes either by name, id, cssSelector, xPath etc. Now, i'm working on another project aimed at automating the regression test for the application. This application was built using ZK Framework (mainly because of its security feature). One of the feature of ZK is the dynamic id attribute. It generates a new id upon login or refresh. This is making the selenium development work difficult. This is a huge application. I have tried using xPath but that hasn't been successful. Any idea of other solutions out there that work specifically for ZK typed application from Selenium WebDriver perspective. Often times, the only thing present in the html is the id (which changes) and the type
Java 8
Selenium 3.11.0

Comment: The best advice I have heard for testing web ui is **don't** (from one of Uncle Bob's talks somewhere). Using MVVM you can come pretty close to testing the ui without the need for a tool like Selenium.
If you have to use Selenium [this small talk](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2013/July/ZK_Testing_with_Selenium_IDE) might help.

Comment: You can use extra css classes or use a custom Implementation of the idgenerator created for testing, so all ID's will have the same value each time you test.

Answer (score 0):

You have options when testing a ZK client with selenium.
Basically, you either use an ID generator to set fixed IDs during testing, or you use components IDs with the zk.$('$id') and jq('$id') client-side selectors

You can go further, but that should already cover 99% of the use-cases

more info here:
https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Testing/Testing_Tips

and there:
https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Client-side_Reference/General_Control/Client-side_selection_of_elements_and_widgets